# Showing help file (.chm) from executable

Tags: c#, wpf, clickonce, installshield

I have a wpf/c# application where I have a .chm file that I would like to display.  I have put this .chm file in the bin/debug and bin/release directory of my project.  I call this file with the following code.

```
System.Windows.Forms.Help.ShowHelp(null, "ConversionData.chm");
```

When I run my application from visual studio everything works as desired.  However, when I create a msi with InstallShield or just create a clickOnce application it does not work.  I know that I am missing something but not sure what.  Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: I just use Process.Start to open my help file. Also, when creating your installer, make sure you're also including the help file. If it's not in the installer, when attempting to run it, the application cannot find it.

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work.  Please show us the Exception message and stack trace.

Comment: I click on the button that opens the file and nothing happens in the executable that is installed on the machine.  There is no exception or stack trace.  That is why I think I am not including the file in the correct place.  Just not sure where that is right now.

Comment: Does the .chm file exist? Have you tried calling `ShowHelp` with the full path to the file, possibly including the `file://` prefix (like the [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/81ee1k5y(v=vs.110).aspx) example suggests)?

Answer (score 1):

```
        string fbPath = Application.StartupPath;
        string fname = "help.chm";
        string filename = fbPath + @"\" + fname;
        FileInfo fi = new FileInfo(filename);
        if (fi.Exists)
        {
            Help.ShowHelp(this, filename, HelpNavigator.Find, "");
        }
```

Be sure you have the file at the location where the application is located

**While creating setup file be sure u have included the help file**

[image]

Comment: where is the screen pic taken from?  What were you using to the setup file?

Comment: This screenshot is taken from **application folder** of the setup and deployment project. I am using setup and deployment project in vs 2013

Answer (score 1):

Add the chm file to your application in Visual Studio. Set the content type to "copy always". This will ensure it copies it to the \bin\ folder, and gets included in your deployment.